# Header Location not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a basic login and registration page and on completion of the change password form I want to redirect to changepassword.php?success. The redirected page works fine if entered into a browser, however when submitting the form it reloads the changepassword.php page instead of ?success and everything from the php code block down doesn't display (i.e. the form, column right and footer). Below is my changepassword.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php 
include ("storescripts/init.php");
protect_page();
include ("includes/overall/head.php");

if (empty($_POST) ===  false){
$required_fields = array('current_password','password','password_again');
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) == true) {
        $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
        break 1;
    }
}
if ($_POST['current_password'] === $member_data['mem_password']) {
    if(trim($_POST['password']) !== trim($_POST['password_again'])){
        $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
    } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) <6) {
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = 'Your current password is incorrect';
}
}
?>
<body>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_header.php");?>
<div id="mainDivShort">
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <div id="divBreak"></div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_left.php"); ?>
    <div id="middleContent">
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
echo 'You have been registered successfully';
} else {

    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        //echo "**********************";
        change_password($session_mem_id, $_POST['password']);
        header('Location: changepassword.php?success');
        exit();
    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }

    ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <ul>
                <li>Current Password*: <br> <input type="password"
                    name="current_password">
                </li>
                <li>New Password*: <br> <input type="password" name="password">
                </li>
                <li>Repeat New Password*: <br> <input type="password"
                    name="password_again">
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Change">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
    <?php include ("includes/overall/column_right.php"); ?>
</div>
<?php include ("includes/overall/template_footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>
```

And just incase you need to look at the change password function:

```
function change_password($mem_id, $password) {
$mem_id = (int)$mem_id;

mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `mem_password` = '$password' WHERE `mem_id` = $mem_id");
}
```

The password updates fine on the database, it just purely doesn't redirect to the success page.
Thanks in advance

Comment: header will work if you don't make an "echo" or "print" before, so don't output anything before the `header`

Comment: Header needs to come before any output and before any html.

Comment: It makes no sense of using `header` if you output any html before that

Comment: Ok, but the 'echo 'You have been registered successfully';' only becomes true is the conditions to the if statement below are met. So how else could this be laid out?

Answer (score 0):

Header directives must come before content, any content, incuding line breaks, spaces, html, etc... otherwise it's too late to send headers.  As soon as 1 bit of content is sent, the headers have already gone.

Comment: Ok, but the 'echo 'You have been registered successfully';' only becomes true is the conditions to the if statement below are met. So how else could this be laid out?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot put `header('Location: changepassword.php?success');` after outputting any content. Also `header` redirects should contain absolute path.

Comment: Not the downvoter but its not necessary to use `absolute path`

Comment: @Mr.Alien HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: